# Plotting wtih seaborn - time evolution of number of my entity over years

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have `pandas` dataframe representing documents which contain 3 columns - Year, Name, Type.

I am trying to create a bar plot which will show the time evolution of my documents over years and it will also separate them by types.

So when I have 3 years (2015, 2016, 2017) and 2 types (Good, Bad), my graph will have 6 bars (2 for every year) and height of the bar will be a number of documents in that year of that type.

I was trying to do that like this:

```
data1['Name'] = 1
sns.barplot(x="Year", y="Name", hue="Type", data=data1)
```

because I thought that barplot will sum the values of `Names` column, but it is not working like that.

Sorry if it is dumb question I was searching for the answer but could not find any.

Comment: do you have an output ?

Comment: Can you clarify what is in the `Names` column? Are there numbers in there you want the sum off? Is there any information in the column you really need? Or is every record as combination of `Year` and `Type` enough and do you only need to count those?

Comment: so in order to have the sum you talking about you need to mask your "Name" ... so you need the separate pre processing of you names .... just as example a count of you document name in each year .... Than your document Name pass as the Hue (you can have multiple documents and have the color as the distinction) ... otherwise you can't do the count on the name ...

Comment: @HielkeWalinga yes that is true '...every record as combination of Year and Type enough and do you only need to count those'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to count each distinct record of combination of `Year` and `Type`

```
sns.countplot(data=data1, x="Year", hue="Type")
```

Suppose you want to count each distinct record of combination of `Year`, `Type` and `Name`

```
filtered_data = data1.drop_duplicates(subset=["Year", "Type", "Name"])
sns.countplot(data=filtered_data, x="Year", hue="Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
g = sns.catplot(x="Year", hue="Type", col="Name", data=data1, kind="count")
```

> For your task *catplot()* will work.
>
> Use `catplot()` to combine a `countplot()` and a `FacetGrid`. **This allows
>   grouping within additional categorical variables.** Using `catplot()` is
>   safer than using `FacetGrid` directly, as it ensures synchronization of
>   variable order across facets:

- Here I show the count of *`Names`* by putting int into the columns
- by *`day`* (in your case by the year)
- and coloring by *`sex`*(in your case by *`Type`*)

> An example why *`catplot()`* with facets is required and that the data
>   need to be modified accordingly:

```
sns.catplot(x="day", hue="sex", col="time", data=data1, kind="count")
```

> This is the correct way to make a plot with categorical data for better visualization.

- You don't need to make column *`"Names"`* 1, because you are just assigning 1 to every observation. (I bet is the names of the documents are there.) So you want to  separate for `"Good" vs "Bad"` and for every `year`.

Generate the following:

[image: Example showing the power of facets:]

[image: Generated using the titanic dataset modified with your code]

[seaborn.countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)

Comment: If you don't have multiple facets, the `catplot` is not really necessary. The returned object is also not a normal matplotlib `ax`, but a facetgrid `g`. This object provide some different methods than the normal `ax`. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html?highlight=facetgrid

Comment: The name document is incorect the way is setup ... so if the name will include the list of the documents than facets is the way to go. right now is just 1 for all and "theoretically" is not making sense because is just a count ... for this reason simulated the data to show that ...